# place x to close out dialog box in jquery

Tags: jquery, dialog

I like to be able to place x on the top right corner of the dialog box instead of close text. Also, I like to be ablet o drag this dialog box, can you help how to do these two things in jquery?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
            jQuery(document).ready( function(){       
                jQuery("#lin").click( showDialog );

                //variable to reference window
                $myWindow = jQuery('#myDiv');

                //instantiate the dialog
                $myWindow.dialog({ height: 600,
                    width: 700,
                    modal: true,
                    draggable: true,
                    position: 'center',
                    autoOpen:false,
                    title:'Hello World',
                    overlay: { opacity: 0.5, background: 'black'}
                    });
                }

            );
        //function to show dialog   
        var showDialog = function() {
            //if the contents have been hidden with css, you need this
            $myWindow.show(); 
            //open the dialog
            $myWindow.dialog("open");
            }

        //function to close dialog, probably called by a button in the dialog
        var closeDialog = function() {
            $myWindow.dialog("close");
        }


    </script>

    </head>

    <body>

    <div id="myDiv">
        <p>this is a test</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you using jQueryUI for this dialog?

Comment: @ReLeaf, yes I am using jquery ui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what you have implemented above looks pretty complicated for what you are trying to do. Here's a jsFiddle that shows a more basic example and seems to fulfill what you're trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/pgNVa/2/

I pretty much stole the code directly from the [jQueryUI docs](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Hope this helps.

```
<a href="#" id="lin">Click Me!</a>   
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog" style="display:none;">
   <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
   $("#lin").click(function(){
     $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
   });
});
</script>
```

​

Comment: I dont get the x title background colour. do you have the css that goes along with this?

Comment: Yes, it's loaded with the default jQueryUI css which you can see in the resources in the fiddle I linked to. Check the docs that I linked to for the complete example.

Let me know if that works for you.

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

Comment: this is great. Sorry to drag this, but I am missing the image for x. do you know what is called?

Comment: When you download the base jQueryUI library, you get the CSS, JS and images for every implementation they provide. The images are a sprite that would come in the package. http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png 

Don't forget to mark the above as the correct answer if I got it right.   ; )

Comment: I know I already accepted your answer which works. I just have a one quick question. I like to change the defaul color for the heading section of the dialog box. It is currently orange. Any pointers how to do that?

Comment: What is awesome about jQueryUI is that they have a themeroller. There's a gallery of themes to choose from or you can create your own. Just download the assets that come with the theme and link to them in your HTML. http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/